# Comment two independent cells on different Sheets in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

There are two worksheets in workbook in Excel. Input box needs to be called into which we set sheet #A, cell number and comment (text) and sheet #B, cell number (on sheet #B) and comment. In result we have two comments in two different cells on different sheets. Is that possible, could you please help me out with VBA code on this?

Well, i came up with this so far,

```
Sub Comment()

  Dim scomment As String
  Dim ssheet As String
  Dim scell As Range
  
  Dim scomment2 As String
  Dim ssheet2 As String
  Dim scell2 As Range
  
  
ssheet = InputBox("Provide a sheet name..")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ssheet).Activate
Set scell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please specify cell", Type:=8)
scell.Activate
scomment = InputBox("Enter your comment for first part", "Comments")
ActiveCell.NoteText Text:=scomment
ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 12
ActiveCell.Font.FontStyle = "MS Reference Sans Serif"
ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False

ssheet2 = InputBox("Provide a sheet name..")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ssheet2).Activate
Set scell2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please specify cell", Type:=8)
scell2.Activate
scomment2 = InputBox("Enter your comment for second part", "Comments")
ActiveCell.NoteText Text:=scomment2
ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 12
ActiveCell.Font.FontStyle = "MS Reference Sans Serif"
ActiveCell.Comment.Visible = False
End Sub
```

But would be cool, if i could see only one inputbox that takes values for Sheet name #1, cell #1, comment #1, Sheet name #2, cell #2, comment #2 and executed accordingly so that we do not need to activate sheets, everything will happen "under the hood". I dont have sufficient skills to make that. hope someone will help out.

Comment: What does "Provide a sheet name.." mean? To provide a sheet name in the range of the **existing sheets**? If so, shouldn't it be better that the `InputBox` to show the enumeration of the existing sheets and away to choose one of them? If not, should it be different and in such a case a new sheet should be inserted, named and used in the next step? Please, better clarify this aspect.

Comment: To have stuff happen without changing what is on the screen, avoid all use of `Activate` and `Select`. Instead of `scell.Activate` and `ActiveCell.stuff` you can just do `scell.stuff`.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. You should only select the cells where the comments to be placed (from the sheets you want). Then, place the comments text in the same `InputBox`, separated by "|" (My first comment|My second comment):

```
Sub Comment()
  Dim scomment As String, scell As Range, scell2 As Range
  
 Set scell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please specify first cell to place a comment, selecting it and pressing OK", Type:=8)
 Set scell2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please specify second cell to place a comment, selecting it and pressing OK", Type:=8)
 If Not scell.MergeCells And Not scell2.MergeCells Then
    If scell.cells.Count > 1 Or scell2.cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 End If
 scomment = InputBox("Enter your comment for both cells, separated by ""|"" (without double quotes)!", "Comments")
 With scell
    .NoteText text:=Split(scomment, "|")(0)
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 12
    .Font.FontStyle = "MS Reference Sans Serif"
    .Comment.Visible = False
 End With
 With scell2
    .NoteText text:=Split(scomment, "|")(1)
    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 12
    .Font.FontStyle = "MS Reference Sans Serif"
    .Comment.Visible = False
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. but i have little problem, my cells are merged so this sub doesn't work properly. so ive added  `If scell.Cells(1, 1).Count > 1 Or scell2.Cells(1, 1).Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`.. everything works but then, after comment is added to different sheets i get error message "Object variable or With block variable is not set". could you provide solution to this please?

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk I do not remember anything about involved merge cells... I will adapt the code to accept more cells only in case of merge cells.

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk Did you find some time to test the updated code? If tested, didn't it work as you need?

Comment: still getting same warning "Object variable or With block variable is not set"

Comment: can you advise how to fix it? Still getting "Object variable or With block variable is not set"

Comment: It looks to be something specific to your workbook, or using way. I can helo only if you share the workbook. You can send it on my personal mail (see it on my profile). If anything confidential, please clean it before sending. Or use a transfer site. But announce me if sending by mail...

Comment: i have sent you the file by email. thank you in advance! if you will comment ports 1 on R1 and R2, then you get this message "Object variable.."

Comment: OK. I will look at it in about 2 hours, when I will be in front of a computer.

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk I am testing it and it works as it should. I cannot imagine how you try using it... Do you have AnyDesk installed? If so, I can connect to your computer, if you send its ID, and see how you try accomplishing this (simple) task. When run the code and you are asked to select/specify a cell, **what are you doing**?

Comment: i have sent you the video by mail. please, find time to watch

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk What I can see, not being correct, is the fact that after first `InbutBox` window to select the first cell, **you do not press `OK`**, you close the window by clicking its top right `X`. In this way, first (necessary) cell does not exist. Why do you do that? Is it only a mistake done when made this video clip? The code **needs two cells** to be set. I can make it to need only one such a input window, to select both cells, but **if you are able to define a specific algorithm** to set the second starting from the first one address. For instance, the same address in sheet 1...

Comment: But forget the last suggested approach, **in this very moment**! We firstly must be sure that you use the code as it should be used...

Comment: no, i didn't click on X, just hovered it while moving mouse to OK. where do you see i click on X? no no

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk This is what I can see of second 13...

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk Can you install AnyDesk and let me connect to test it myself, but **on your environment**?

Comment: look at second 14th. i am clicking on OK on that window

Comment: no, i don't have anydesk and can't install it there unfortunately

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk But, is the first comment created as it should? Is the second one created, without formatting it? I cannot understand what's happening, since it works smooth  on my computer. It should be something on yours. What Excel/Office version do you use?

Comment: yes, comments are created even though "Object variable.." window appeared.  am using Excel 365

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk I am using Excel 365, too, and it works without any problem... Now, the strange thing is that your first `Cell` it is correctly updated from `Font` point of view. Is this statement correct? I believe that only because it looks that the code passes that part and has a problem only in the second part... This is what I could see in the video clip.

Comment: i am sorry, something is wrong with my version of office. your code works great. many thanks. i will try to sort out with my office. my bad

Comment: @Aleksei Kovaltsuk It is good that it works for you, too. But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick  the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, people searching for a similar issue will know that the code works as it should. Our community main purpose is to make as many people as possible learn...